# Change the default camera in jitsi-sdk for android

Tags: android, react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm developing my own video-conference Android-App and using the jitsi-sdk.
But I want to set the back camera of my Smartphone as default. The user can change it once the conference is launched, but my goal is to change it before the conference begins without user interactions.

I already tried to switch camera by creating a cameraCapturer/videoCapturer, but the JitsiMeetActivity opens the front camera. Also I tried to use the putExtra-method for the launch-intent.

So my Activity extends from the JitsiMeetActivity and after Setting the JitsiMeetConferenceOptions the Conference is launched as followed:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, JitsiMeetActivity.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.setAction("org.jitsi.meet.CONFERENCE");
   intent.putExtra("JitsiMeetConferenceOptions", options);
   startActivity(context, JitsiMeetActivity);
```

After that, I can't change anything programmatically.

Is there any way to get the settings before the JitsiMeetActivity is opened?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: hello, did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi, it seems like the only solution is to checkout the whole sdk and change the javascript in the background which creates the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late answer, but i find solution... you need customize jitsi android sdk, for doing this you need mac, and setting it using [docs](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk)

After setting sdk, you need change only one line of code in CameraCaptureController.java in react-native-webrtc lib folder

From this:

```
@Override
protected VideoCapturer createVideoCapturer() {
    String deviceId = ReactBridgeUtil.getMapStrValue(this.constraints, "deviceId");
    String facingMode = ReactBridgeUtil.getMapStrValue(this.constraints, "facingMode");
    return createVideoCapturer(deviceId, facingMode);
}
```

To this:

```
@Override
protected VideoCapturer createVideoCapturer() {
    String deviceId = ReactBridgeUtil.getMapStrValue(this.constraints, "deviceId");
    String facingMode = ReactBridgeUtil.getMapStrValue(this.constraints, "facingMode");
    return createVideoCapturer(deviceId, "environment");
}
```

And in your terminal do: ./gradlew assembleRelease

Instructions to build own jitsi-meet-sdk:

1. **clone** project from github
2. run **npm install** in your terminal in root jitsi folder
3. in **jitsi-meet(root)/android** folder you need run this command: *./android/scripts/release-sdk.sh /tmp/repo*
4. build android project in android studio from folder **jitsi-meet(root)/android**
5. change code from **sdk**
6. build apk from folder **jitsi-meet(root)/android** with running this command: **./gradlew assembleRelease**

Comment: Back then i hoped there is a way without checking respectively cloning the sdk. But this seems to be the only solution, so accepted ;)